how can i show the terminal output and matplotlib graphic on django web
I got no clue how to do it. this is my py code. #

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('Sepal Length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Width')
plt.title('Iris Veri Seti')
plt.colorbar(label='Class')
plt.show()
Veri setini eğitim ve test setlerine ayırma
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

classifiers = {
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(),
    "Gradient Boosting": GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    "AdaBoost": AdaBoostClassifier()
}

results = {}
for name, clf in classifiers.items():
    clf.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_scaled)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
    results[name] = {"Accuracy": accuracy, "Precision": precision, "Recall": recall, "F1 Score": f1}

print("Sınıflandırma Algoritması\tAccuracy\tPrecision\tRecall\tF1 Score")
for name, metrics in results.items():
    print(f"{name}\t{metrics['Accuracy']:.4f}\t{metrics['Precision']:.4f}\t{metrics['Recall']:.4f}\t{metrics['F1 Score']:.4f}")


is there a easy way to shot it on web page. could be django or something else but it must be on web page.
this is the matplotlib output
this is the output of the terminal

first you have to learn Django or flask. And learn how works web pages because they work in different way than console or GUI - especially protocol HTTP but also HTML, CSS. And later try to convert your code to web page.

in Django, flask (and many other web frameworks) you create functions which use return to send all text (mostly HTML) to client web browser - so you get all text in variable and you use one return to send it all (instead of using many print()). And if you use <a src="link_to_file_with_mathplotlib_image"> then browser will also load image - but all this needs to know HTML and HTTP

BTW: if you want to ask user for data to your plot then you may have to learn also how works <form> and maybe how to write scripts in JavaScript

other idea: you can share code as Jupyter Notebook on pages like Google Colab or  nbviewer.org and then people can see plot and image using web browser. But they will see also source code.

other idea: you can use Python module streamlit to create web pages. It simpler than flask and you don't have to know all details - but sometimes it makes problem when you already know how works HTTP, HTML, CSS, JS and you want to control all details
